# jQuery Replace dot to comma and round it

Tags: javascript

```
var calcTotalprice = function () {
    var price1 = parseFloat($('#price1').html());
    var price2 = parseFloat($('#price2').html());
    overall = (price1+price2);
    $('#total-amount').html(overall);
}

var price1 = 1.99;
var price2 = 5.47;
```

How to add function to change dot to comma in price number and round it to two decimal

Comment: -1 as I don't think this question does show any research effort regarding how to replace text, how to round a number or how to specify trailing decimals, using JavaScript.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use ".toFixed(x)" function to round your prices:

```
price1 = price1.toFixed(2)
```

And then you can use method ".toString()" to convert your value to string:

```
price1 = price1.toString()
```

Also, you can use method ".replace("..","..")" to replace "." for ",":

```
price1 = price1.replace(".", ",")
```

Result:

```
price1 = price1.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",")
```

**Updated answer**

.toFixed already returns a string, so doing .toString() is not needed.
This is more than enough:

```
price1 = price1.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
```

Comment: Note that `replace` with a string as the search parameter will only replace the first one. Of course, that's all the OP needs in this case.

Comment: +1: I'm not going to leave my answer here for it being downvoted with the same solution as yours. So I just +1 yours instead. The only comment regarding your solution I have is that OP mentioned `rounding` so if that is the case you might need to add that into your answer. I understood the requirement to be `1.99` ends up as `2,00`, unless off course OP miss-used the term rounding.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: `toFixed` does rounding. `(1.999).toFixed(2)` comes out `"2.00"`. (Note that `1.99` rounded to two decimal places is still `1.99`, not `2.00`. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Very nice. Thank you, that is very good information. I will keep that in mind. +1 However, as OP has a input of `1.99` and was asking for rounding and comma, would we still not have to use `Math.round` to get 2,00, if that was the expected result?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: But clearly `1.99` is *not* meant to become `2.00`. There's no point in two digits of precision if your accuracy is lower than two digits.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm sure you are right, it is just the wording of the OP `...and round it to two decimal`. Didn't make sense to me to use the word rounding so I assumed it was `2,00`, otherwise rounding is not right there. In fact the whole mentioning of rounding or decimal places is not needed in that case as the numbers are already 2 decimals in regards to the given code in the question. Yes, though, I would think you are right, the requirement just sounded confusing.

Comment: Isn't toString useless? toFixed already convert to String, right?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
var price1 = 1.99234;

// Format number to 2 decimal places
var num1 = price1.toFixed(2);

// Replace dot with a comma
var num2 = num1.toString().replace(/\./g, ',');
```

Comment: +1 as it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tcGuu/ I'm not sure who that person was that downvoted all the other answer with the same result as accepted answer. Very fishy.

Comment: Why are you using `parseFloat` on something that's **already a number**. Your `parseFloat` is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to round and replace with a class selector.
This code formats 10.0 to 10,00

```
$('.formatInteger').each(function(){
  let int = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2)
  $(this).html(int.toString().replace(".", ","))
})
```